# Script File to get Track Names From iTunes

Tags: itunes

I am working on a project and I need to get the name of track that is currently playing on iTunes. You can think this project as very basic version of Last.fm Scrobbler.

When any user plays any song on his iTunes library, I need to report the name of this song on a web site.

But I do not know how to start. Can you guys recommend me some links or starting points to code a script file for iTunes on Windows?

Thank you!